# jquery plugin draggable slider with multiple areas like stack chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, slider, draggable

I have been looking for a jquery plugin around that does this, but seems like there isn't much like that out there.

Basically I would like to provide a widget that has handles to allocate percentages by dragging.  It is more like a horizontal stack chart whose lines can be dragged.  In other words, a horizontal "tube" or pie is divided into different sections, but can be dragged by the user to determine the desirable percentage for each section.  New sections should also be able to be added and removed on the fly.

Is there anything jquery widget plugin that does this?  I have found a lot of good drag and drop plugin, lots of good stack chart, pie chart plugins, but seems like i haven't found one that does both.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at d3? It's a javascript library that can do what you're describing.

Comment: Thanks for recommending. That seems powerful. But seems like the "dynamic" part of it is still pretty lacking, when it comes to adding or removing sections.

Comment: I haven't personally done any dynamic element additions with d3, but I was pointed to this example of someone who did: [link](http://littleearth.ca/pottymouth/)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose for the above scenario either a slider with fixed minimum would work fine. The link for the jquery for this is http://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemin  The example stated here can be changed according to the need in this case %.

Comment: the slider here is the range slider where in we can set the range by sliding i.e. dragging the slider. We can also fetch the range that we have selected by dragging the control. It does support multiple handles.